# OCaml: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type MyFoo.ty (except MyFoo.ty is int)

Tags: ocaml

Here's my code:

foo.ml:

```
module type ITy = sig
   type ty
end

module type IFoo = sig
   type ty
   val doo: ty -> ty
end

module Make (Ty: ITy): IFoo = struct
   type ty = Ty.ty
   let doo (x:ty) = x
end
```

main.ml:

```
module MyFoo = Foo.Make(struct
   type ty = int
end)

let () = assert(MyFoo.doo 3 = 3)
```

To compile, I use:

```
$ corebuild main.native
```

which gives me:

```
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g -bin-annot -short-paths -thread -package core -ppx 'ppx-jane -as-ppx' -o main.cmo main.ml
File "main.ml", line 5, characters 26-27:
5 | let () = assert(MyFoo.doo 3 = 3)
                              ^
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         MyFoo.ty
Command exited with code 2.
Hint: Recursive traversal of subdirectories was not enabled for this build,
  as the working directory does not look like an ocamlbuild project (no
  '_tags' or 'myocamlbuild.ml' file). If you have modules in subdirectories,
  you should add the option "-r" or create an empty '_tags' file.

  To enable recursive traversal for some subdirectories only, you can use the
  following '_tags' file:

      true: -traverse
      <dir1> or <dir2>: traverse

Compilation unsuccessful after building 4 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:01.
```

I expected my code to compile successfully b.c. I'm an OCaml noob, and when I call the `Foo.Make` functor in main.ml to create `MyFoo` I give it an input struct of `type ty = int`. I'm probably doing something wrong, but have been unsuccessful at finding the documentation that talks about this specifically. Maybe I'm using the wrong operator somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://dev.realworldocaml.org/functors.html#sharing-constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
module type ITy = sig
   type ty
end

module type IFoo = sig
   type ty
   val doo: ty -> ty
end

module Make (Ty: ITy): (IFoo with type ty := Ty.ty) = 
struct
   let doo x = x
end

module MyFoo = Make(struct
   type ty = int
end)

let () = assert(MyFoo.doo 3 = 3)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did find Yawar's comment useful, but never came around to answering my own question. If anyone else runs into this, the important thing is the part that says `(IFoo with type ty := Ty.ty)` which transforms the IFoo interface into another interface that says "expose/share `ty` to the outside world`. These are called sharing constraints.

Comment: Well, I sort of lied b.c. on top of that, `:=` as opposed to just a `=` means use something called destructive substitution which does a further transform to delete all instances of `ty` in the output signature and replace it with the underlying type. IMO it all sounds more complicated than it really is -- an access modifier

Comment: Additionally, this feature is useful b.c. if you had, let's say an inner variant type, then you may want to prevent outside of access of that variant type's constructors and force the outside to use some sort of frontend factory function instead. Again, see Yamar's comment above for the link to the o'reilly book which goes into this in detail with complete examples unlike the ocaml.org tutorials